# Git pull gives "Already up to date" but remote branch shows confilcts

Tags: git, pull-request, git-pull

So I've just recently started using more of git functionality and I'm a bit lost.

- I cloned the repo from `master` branch.
- Did some coding.
- I `git checkeout -b newbranch` then `git commit` and `git push origin newbranch`
- I did pull request in bitbucket but it was pointing to `master` branch and I was told to point it to `develop` branch so I did. Then I got:
  [image]
- So in my terminal i did `git checkout develop` but when I tried to `git pull` I got `Already up to date` message. So if `develop` branch is different than `newbranch` and it's causing conflicts why I can't pull it? What don't I understand here?

I need to get the code from `develop` branch, resolve conflicts and than push it again and do pull request again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflicts you need to solve are between `develop` and `newbranch`.

The two main ways to fix this issue from your local repo are :

1. rebase `newbranch` on top of `develop`

```
# from branch 'newbranch' :
git checkout newbranch

# rebase on top of 'develop' :
git rebase develop

# if you actually need to edit or drop commits along the way, you may use
# an interactive rebase :
git rebase -i develop
```

2. merge `develop` into `newbranch`

```
# from branch 'newbranch' :
git checkout newbranch

# merge 'develop' :
git merge develop
```

Choose whichever way is adapted to your workflow.

You will need to fix conflicts to complete either of these actions -- your remote says that there are some.

---

Once you are satisfied with your updated `newbranch` on your local repo, push it to your remote :

```
git push origin newbranch

# if you ran rebase, you will need to force push your branch :
git push --force-with-lease origin newbranch
```

Comment: The first one worked very well. I did do the second one as I can't merge before resolving the conflicts. Thanks.